# Writing an SDK in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

Basically, I want to make api calls using an SDK I am writing.

I have the following classes:

- Car
- CarData (stores input values needed to create a car like model, make, etc)

Basically to create a car I do the following:

```
[Car carWithData: cardata onSuccess: successHandler onError: errorHandler]
```

that basically is a factory method that creates instance of Car after making an API call request and populating the new Car class with the response and passes that instance to the successHandler.

So "Car" has the above static method to create that car, but also has non-static methods to edit, delete cars (which would make edit, delete API calls to the server)

So when the Car create static method passes a new car to the successHandler by doing the following:

```
successHandler([[Car alloc] initWithDictionary: dictionary)
```

The success handler can go ahead and use that new car to do the following:

```
[car update: cardata]
[car delete]
```

considering the new car object now has an ID for each car that it can pass to the update and delete API calls.

My questions:

- Do I need a cardata object to store user inputs or can I store them in the car object that would also later store the response from all of the api calls?
- How can I improve this model?

With regards to CarData, note that there might be different inputs for the different API calls. So create function might need to know model, make, etc, but find function might need to know the number of items to find, the limit, the start id, etc.

Comment: Would I be correct in assuming `cardata` is passed to the API and that's the only time it's used?

Comment: Please see edit of my response above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, names are very important in building an SDK. Your names are a bit confusing. `CarData` sounds very much like it is related to an `NSData`. The typical name for "a class that holds information about another class" is a "descriptor." So, I would call this `CarDescriptor`. See `UIFont` and `UIFontDescriptor` for inspiration.

Next, your `carWithData:onSuccess:onError:` very much sounds like it should return a `Car`, but it appears to be `void`. I recommend the following:

```
+ (void)createCarWithDescriptor:(CarDescriptor *)descriptor 
                     completion:(void (^)(Car *car, NSError *error))completion;
```

It is preferred to have a [single completion block, rather than two.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18362957/should-my-block-based-api-have-just-completion-or-both-success-and-failure-handl) Do not prefix completion handlers with `on`.

The `CarDescriptor` class should help you with your searching question as well, but it should not include things like limits. You should wrap that in a `CarSearchRequest` (or possibly just a `CarSearch`). See `NSFetchRequest` for inspiration. Whether you pass a `CarDescriptor` or need a full predicate depends on how your service manages searches. (Of course, you could always have code that converts a `CarDescriptor` into a predicate.) Again, look at how `UIFontDescriptor` is used to search for fonts for inspiration.

Comment: Great answer. The famous AFNetwork library uses that pattern (successBlock, failureBlock). I can't stress enough how awful is having such interface. Thanks for pointing that ;-)

Comment: If I want to validate the properties of the descriptor .. where do I add the valdiation inside the descriptor class?

Comment: It depends on what "validation" means. Typically it is best to make it impossible to pass illegal values (using enums rather than strings for instance). But if it has to be validated on the server (confirming that a make and model combination actually exists), then you should do that during car creation. The description should never talk to the server. It is merely a description. It is legal to describe a thing that does not exist.

Comment: should it be carWithDescriptor (the name of the function)? just like fontWithDescriptor?

Comment: Also do you know the name of this design pattern of using a descriptor  and such?

Comment: I suggest adding a verb (`create`) to the beginning of the method name because it does not return a `Car`. It requests that a `Car` be created and returned at some future point. Methods that begin with a noun should return that noun.

Comment: I've seen this pattern called "Descriptor." It has a lot in common with Gamma's "Memento." For a short discussion in Java, see http://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/Database/The_Descriptor_Pattern